# List left after slicing in python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to find an elegant way to obtain the list left after slicing.

Here's my code:

```
original_list = [2, 4, 5,8,9, 11]
for i in range(len(original_list)):
 left_over_list = original_list[0:i].append(original_list[i+1:]
```

Aside from issues regarding managing the index, this method really is very hacky.
Is there a way to do it.
In essence after the first iteration, I should have,

```
[4, 5, 8, 9, 11]
```

and after the second,

```
[2, 5, 8, 9, 11]
```

and so on.
Can someone help me with this.

Comment: So do you want it to output 6 new lists each missing one value, or do you not want new lists.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> list(combinations(original_list, 5))[::-1]
[(4, 5, 8, 9, 11),
 (2, 5, 8, 9, 11),
 (2, 4, 8, 9, 11),
 (2, 4, 5, 9, 11),
 (2, 4, 5, 8, 11),
 (2, 4, 5, 8, 9)]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want elegance, take advantage of the implicitness of the addition operator that the list datatype implements.

```python
>>> slice = lambda mylist, li, ri: mylist[:li] + mylist[ri:]
>>> l = list(range(10))
>>> slice(l, 3, 6)
[0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I'm not sure if this is what you were going for, though.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer @AshwiniChaudhary's answer to my own, but I'm always a fan of list comprehension:

```
combinations = [
    [value for index, value in enumerate(original_list) if index != current]
    for current in range(len(original_list)]
```

Then if you're just looking for a single 'list left' at a given index, you can remove the outer layer and set `current` to your index.